# mod_rewrite and GET value + MVC

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, get

So I'm trying to use mod_rewrite on the URL produced by a GET form to redirect it from this:

`index.php?page=trade&stocksymbol=GOOG`

to this:

`trade/GOOG`

I already have this line in my .htaccess (`Multiviews` is turned off):

```
RewriteRule ^trade$ index.php?page=trade [L]    
RewriteRule ^trade/(.*)$ index.php?page=trade&stocksymbol=$1 [L]
```

And it works just fine if I manually type **trade/GOOG/** into the address bar.

The problem is that I'm using an MVC model where the controller **index.php** renders a header + footer along with the view **trade.php**, and the form itself is on **trade.php**. I want to get the form to submit and end up at **trade/GOOG** – but since it's a GET form, instead it goes to **trade/trade?stocksymbol=GOOG**.

**trade.php**

```
<form action="trade" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="stocksymbol" size="10" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

**index.php**

```
if (isset($_GET['page']))
    $page = htmlspecialchars($_GET['page']);
else
    $page = 'index';

switch ($page)
{
    case 'trade':
        if (isset($_GET['stocksymbol']))
        {
            $stocksymbol = htmlspecialchars($_GET['stocksymbol']);
        }
        render('templates/header', array('title' => 'Trade')); //render() is a function that extracts the array elements into variables and spits out the HTML
        render('trade', array('page' => $page, 'stocksymbol' => $stocksymbol));
        render('templates/footer');
        break;
    ...
```

I know I'm making some rookie mistake here, because I don't quite understand mod_rewrite properly and there's something wrong with the logic but I can't put my finger on it yet. If possible, to keep it simple I'd like to solve this using only mod_rewrite instead of a Javascript solution because I'd like to know if this is possible with mod_rewrite.

**EDIT:**

Turns out my GET request isn't coming through. By looking at `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` in **index.php**, I discovered that the request being sent is `/trade?stocksymbol=GOOG` (suggesting that **index.php** is not receiving the stuff after the `?`).

Also, turning on Developer Tools in Chrome I can see that there is indeed a GET request there each time, but `if (isset($_GET['stocksymbol']))` is false regardless of whether it's in **index.php** or **trade.php**.

So I think mod_rewrite is screwing up my GET request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hunting for a few hours I finally found the answer, and it was much simpler than I thought...

All I had to do was change

`RewriteRule ^trade$ index.php?page=trade [L]`

to

`RewriteRule ^trade$ index.php?page=trade [qsappend]`

Here's where I found the explanation:
http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nwpi711/helpdata/en/48/9266f7aa6b17cee10000000a421937/content.htm

Apologies to John Lin for the red herring – turns out it was the gap in my knowledge rather than something more mysterious. Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 1):

You can either do this with mod_rewrite or in your **index.php**. In php, you just need to check if the request was made directly for `/index.php?page=trade`, and if so, externally redirect. It's going to depend on your code and where you'd want to implement it, but one place you can put it is in the `case` for `'trade'`:

```
case 'trade':
    if (isset($_GET['stocksymbol']))
    {
        $stocksymbol = htmlspecialchars($_GET['stocksymbol']);

        // stuff here to redirect browser
        $self_uri = "/index.php?page=trade";
        if (strncmp($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $self_uri, strlen($self_uri)))
        {
            // if the requested URI starts with /index.php?page=trade, redirect
            header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
            header('Location: /trade/' . $stocksymbol);
            exit();
        }
        // end browser redirect
    }
    render('templates/header', array('title' => 'Trade')); //render() is a function that extracts the array elements into variables and spits out the HTML
    render('trade', array('page' => $page, 'stocksymbol' => $stocksymbol));
    render('templates/footer');
    break;
...
```

A mod_rewrite way of doing this is the same sort of thing. You're checking if the actual request (not the URI in this case, since the rewrite engine changes that) was made for `/index.php?page=trade`, then redirecting the browser:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\ /index\.php\?page=trade&stocksymbol=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /trade/%2? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your detailed answer! I'm still trying to make both of these methods work. Adding the mod_rewrite lines took me to a redirect loop when I typed in **/trade/GOOG** manually, and there was no change if I pressed submit the normal way.

However I've just realised though testing that `if (isset($_GET['stocksymbol']))` is returning false on **index.php** and even on **trade.php** as well! What could that mean? Looking at it in Chrome I can clearly see there's a GET request there...

Comment: Also I checked what `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` was in **index.php** and it was `/trade?stocksymbol=GOOG`, so I guess that means it's doing mod_rewrite beforehand.